# Ошибка:invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

Относительно несколько месяцев назад я начал изучать питон и я решил написать небольшой калькулятор,но столкнулся с такой проблемой-при подавании в переменны числа формата float выдается вот такая системная ошибка.Я пытался исправить с помощью if и else но ничего не помогло
Как сделать так чтобы программа принимала значения формата и int и float???????
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы хотите обрабатывать числа с плавающей точкой при вводе, зачем вы пытаетесь конвертировать его в целое число?  Чтобы удивиться ошибке?  Поставьте корректный тип `a = float(input(f'a='))`, затем, если нужно, приведите к целому типу `a=int(a)`

Comment: @СергейШ мне не совсем понятно что вы написали в виде кода

Comment: принимайте все числа в float, а вывод можете форматировать, например x = 3 / 3.0 print(f"{x:g}") '1' x = 3 / 2 print(f"{x:g}") '1.5'

Comment: Зачем вам разделения int и float? Потому что, при выводе результата вас смущает ноль после точки?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте просто переводить число во float внутри try

```
a = float(input(f'a= '))
b = float(input(f'b= '))
```